# How to animate a textblock in XAML to show it completly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a long list seector that shows an `image`, two `textblocks` (name and description and other `image` to share the item. The problem is that the description and the usually are larger than the size of the piece of grid where they are so I can show only the beginning. What I want is scroll automatically the text of the `textblocks` to the left using an animation to show it completely. Is this posible? 
The code of my xaml project is this.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="GaleryLongListSelector" SelectionChanged="GaleryLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="100"  toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image Width="80" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="80" Source="{Binding ThumbImage}" Margin="5,0">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtProjectName" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,10,0,0"   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtProjectDescript" Text="Aqui iria una descripcion muy larga del faldksjfjkldjfkldajsfkljaslfkjasldfjlasdjfkl"    Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="/Images/share.png" Width="80" Tap="Image_Tap" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True" x:Name="ContextMenu" >
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem  Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.MainPagePanoramaItemGalleryContextMenuDelete}" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem  Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.MainPagePanoramaItemGalleryContextMenuRename}" Click="Rename_Click"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Just wrap the description TextBlock in an ScrollViewer and set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to auto.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtProjectDescipt" .../>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What about wrapping it in a ScrollViewer ?

Comment: I don't understand you @Miiite . I tryed too to set the TextWrapping="Wrap" property in the TextBlock but without any result.

Comment: I tried this too but without any result. If I use a scroll viewer I can scroll it manually but I want to do it automatically. Other problem using this code is that when I drop the text it returns to the default position.

Comment: take a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7a391faa-8607-4c2b-84d4-4ee3bf55a679/marquee-scrolling-text?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

What I meant in my comment is, have you tried using this :

```
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock Text="Mon texte de test" />
            </ScrollViewer>
```

If your text is too long, it should make it scrollable.
Then you just have to create your animation, to automatically scroll it